# CSS - floating elements lose alignment

Tags: html, css

I hope someone can explain this to me and offer a solution..

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue and to explain the question

http://jsfiddle.net/s6ow1oq3/

Here is the question..

When elements such as `<li>` or `<div>` are floated left and they are set to a particular width but **they don't/can't have a fixed height**,,, how can I insure that element that breaks into new row gets aligned to the beginning of the next row?

In the fiddle example the second example demonstrates the issue while the first one is desired.

Here is the fiddle code too:

**CSS:**

```
li {
    list-style:    none;
}

#one li, #two li {
    width:    22%;
    float:    left;
    margin:   7px;
    padding:  7px;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:    both;
    float:    none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Unordered List Examples -->

<div id="one">
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>

<hr/>

<div id="two">
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c1<br/>c2<br/>c3<br/>c4</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
```

Comment: clearing the float.  `float:clear` on the 5th element on a 4 column floated grid.  If you can use CSS3 styles, you can try some of the nth style rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` - the most under-appreciated display type IMO.

**The main thing you can't do is have 100% width coverage, but since your example doesn't require the items to butt up against one another, it's a perfect use case for inline-block**

The trick is to make sure that all of your width's and margins add up to roughly 99% instead of 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/s6ow1oq3/3/

```
#one li, #two li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:    22%;
    margin:   1.2%;
    padding:  7px;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just worked that one out myself too http://jsfiddle.net/s6ow1oq3/1/ .. I am leaning towards this solution and I actually need a solution that does not give me 100% coverage too.

Comment: The `vertical-align: top` is important.  In a nutshell, you get all the benefits of floats, but instead each DIV/LI is treated like a letter in a sentence: when a letter reaches the end of a line, it wraps back around to the beginning of the next line.  The only problem is you also are affected by line height and word spacing... which prevents pixel-perfect sizing and the whole "can't equal 100%" thing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's always 4 columns, you could use `li:nth-child(4n + 1)` to clear the first element on every row. For example:

```
li:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ow1oq3/2/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't quite limit myself to fixed number of columns. I used this in cases where I had the option to do that. Thanks!